# Sorting date in datatable

Tags: datatables, momentjs

I'm trying to sort dates in my datatable like `DD/MM/YYYY` (day, month, year) .
I was following https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/ .

but all the date sorts seem to be deprecated and point to the datetime plugin: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18

I don't seem to be able to get the datetime plugin working to sort. I tried the old way, with date. The initialize looks like this:

```
var historiektable = $('#dataTableHistoriek').DataTable({
    "paging" : false,
    "ordering" : true,
    "scrollCollapse" : true,
    "searching" : false,
    "columnDefs" : [{"targets":3, "type":"date"}],
    "bInfo": true
});
```

Without sorting it shows the table results like this:

[image: Without sorting, I get this from the backend]

When I put `ordering:true` 2 of the 2016 dates appear somewhere else in the list (so, not in order you would expect)

[image: With sorting on date]

With everything pointing at [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) I thought I needed to sort with that. But I'm not sure how.

I saw `$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY');` somewhere, but I understood that the `fn` doesn't work with this newest version of datatables anymore?

Anyone knows how to sort dates?

Comment: Was to late, you can very easily do it yourself -> **http://jsfiddle.net/mwhpy9eb/** more saitsifying than a plugin you are not sure how works or is having exaggerated dependencies.

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't work at first.

Comment: Please look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70648930/2777138) for an alternate way to sort data by date.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`date-eu`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-eu) sorting plugin to sort dates in the format `DD/MM/YY`.

Include the following JS file `//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/sorting/date-eu.js` and use the code below:

```
var historiektable = $('#dataTableHistoriek').DataTable({
    "paging" : false,
    "ordering" : true,
    "scrollCollapse" : true,
    "searching" : false,
    "columnDefs" : [{"targets":3, "type":"date-eu"}],
    "bInfo": true
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was considering it earlier but I was hoping for a more universal solution. I guess there is no since [Ultimate date sorting](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) did not work for me and this did.

Answer (score 7):

The example of [Gyrocode.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3549014/gyrocode-com) seems the most effective. A recent solution says to use [Moments.js](https://momentjs.com/) but it does not work in my case. [date-eu](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/sorting/date-eu.js) is deprecated by [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) but it works perfectly.

If you want to sort by date and time using the **date format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm**, use [date-euro](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/sorting/date-euro.js) in the same way.

```
var table = $('#example-table').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{ 'targets': 0, type: 'date-euro' }],
    order: [0, 'desc'],
});
```

For beginners, add the JS file [date-euro](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/sorting/date-euro.js) to your site. Then add "columnDefs" in your code to indicate which column [date-euro](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/sorting/date-euro.js) should be applied: targets = indicates the column containing the dates to sort, type = indicates the [date-euro](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/sorting/date-euro.js) function to apply to the column. Finally, add "order" to apply the sort you want.

Comment: you are a life saver bro, 2019 and you did it.

Answer (score 3):

Please look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70648930/2777138) for an alternate way to sort data by date.

Sample code::

```
<td data-search="21st November 2016 21/11/2016" data-order="1479686400">
    21st November 2016
</td>

$('#dataTable').DataTable({
    "order": [[10, 'desc']],
});
```

Thank You,

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

For me, using ASP.NET core 3.1 with MVC, I used a data-sort attribute on my <td> for the datatables:

```
                    <td data-sort="@(item.DueDateTime.Ticks)">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DueDateTime)
                    </td>
```

No plug-ins needed

See this link:
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this pen: https://codepen.io/arnulfolg/pen/MebVgx

It uses //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js and //cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/sorting/datetime-moment.js for sorting datatable

To sort the table by default use:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YY');
$('#example').DataTable({ 
       "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]] 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [Plasebo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219024/plasebo) example works, but in my case the MySQL DATE_FORMAT was sorting on month value, not entire date. My solution was to remove the DATE_FORMAT from my SQL statement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YY');
  $('.happyTable').DataTable({
        "ordering": true,
        "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
  });
});
```

**[DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)**(date,'%m/%d/%Y')

**"2003-12-30 00:00:00"**
results in **"12/30/2003"** but sorts on month value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do your own comparator in order to keep the control of how is ordering the dates.

```
 jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
            "ddMmYyyy-pre": function (a) {
                a = a.split('/');
                if (a.length < 2) return 0;
                return Date.parse(a[0] + '/' + a[1] + '/' + a[2]);
            },
            "ddMmYyyy-asc": function (a, b) {
                return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
            },
            "ddMmYyyy-desc": function (a, b) {
                return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
            }
        });
```

As you can see in the above comparator you can choose how to parse the date depending on your data.

And in the columns definition:

```
  "columnDefs": [
            {
                targets: [4], type: "ddMmYyyy"
            }]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an ugly hack that I've used in the past especially when I couldn't quickly modify the DataTable javascript. You can add a hidden span that has the date in a sortable format.

```
<td><span style="visibility:hidden">2006-12-21</span>21/12/2006</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

[test](https://test.com)
***strong text***

```js
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['time-date-sort-pre'] = function(value) {      
    return Date.parse(value);
};
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['time-date-sort-asc'] = function(a,b) {      
    return a-b;
};
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['time-date-sort-desc'] = function(a,b) {
    return b-a;
};

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs : [
        { type: 'time-date-sort', 
          targets: [0],
        }
    ],
    order: [[ 0, "desc" ]]
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This proved WAY trickier than it needed to be. I tried moment, luxon , as well as all the answers above and none was working for my dates (DD/MM/YYYY) format.

It turned out it was as simple as converting my date to iso8601 format and inserting it into the data-order attribute. No other libraries were needed.

```
< td data-order="1479686400">
30/01/2024
 </td>
```

I'm using Asp.net Core but this should work regardless of your framework.