# Datables Dates not sorting correctly

Tags: html, ajax, datatable

I need to sort these dates by DateTime. I have the code below. any help would be greatly appreciated. The column is Submitted and its called CREATED DATE in the ajax I believe. It should be sorting from oldest to newest, Oldest date being at the top. So 11/15 then 5/5 then 5/6 then 5/12. I believe its sorting as if its a string?
[image: Text]

```
 "order": [[1, "asc"]],

"columns": [
                { "name": "ID", "className": "click user-details hidden", "data": "Personnel_Id" },
                { "name": "CREATED_DATE", "className": "click user-details", "data": "CreatedDate"},
                { "name": "QUEUE_TYPE", "className": "click user-details", "data": "ApprovalQueueTypeDisplay" },
```

Comment: Post a working snippet of your issue.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy It should be sorting from oldest to newest, Oldest date being at the top. So 11/15 then 5/5 then 5/6 then 5/12. I believe its sorting as if its a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort datatables with date in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814191/how-to-sort-datatables-with-date-in-descending-order)

Comment: @Dani Actually the answer was looking at the Date functionality in the datatables documentation. It converted the string output to a proper DateTime output. "type": "date"