# Sorting by date on dataTables makes problems

Tags: php, mysql, twig

I have a list view, which should be sorted by date (d-m-y)
The query I run on phpmyadmin processess my data in the right way, sorting my datas in the right way. (If i dump my array, the data is correctly sorted)
When I run my twig page, this sorting doesn't exist anymore: it orders my data in a casual way. I can't understand why. Is that possible that my datatable makes problems? How can i deal with that?

This is my table body:

```
    {% for riga in data.dati %}
    
    {{ riga['order_date']|date('Y-m-d') }}
    -----some others things here------
    
    {% endfor %}
```

And this is my js code:

```
    $(function() {


     $('#tableOrdini').DataTable({
        'info': false,
        'searching': false,
        'language': {
        'url': '{{ asset('myurl') }}',
        },
        'pageLength': 50,
        'scrollY': 600,
        'lengthChange': false,
        'order': [[1, 'desc']],
        columnDefs:[
        {type: 'date-eu', targets:1}
        ]
        });
    });
```

Thank you for dedicate your time to me and for helping me !

ps: this is my view
[image: this is my view]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36984942/17962521)! worked for me : using sorting/date-eu.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can change this 
`'order': [[1, 'desc']],`
to order with `date('Y-m-d')` or a `order_date`

Comment: Thanks ! i've changed the first parameter: it's referring to the column number of the table, so i've changed it to '0' (the first column) instead of '1' (the second column)
thank you so so so much !